# CS50 Vigenere characters not shifting

Tags: c, cs50

My characters are staying the same i.e. if my key is `b` and typed in `hello` in plaintext, it still provides me with `hello`. I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing in getting my alphabet to shift appropriately i.e. I've indexed my alphabet 0-25.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int shift(char c);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Ensure the program has only one command-line
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./vigenere key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    { 
     // Ensure user only enter key in alphabet
     string s = (argv[1]);

    //Make sure command line argument is alpha
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(s[i]) == false)
        {
            printf("Usage: ./vigenere key\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
        // Converting string to integers
        int key = atoi(argv[1]);

        // Prompt user input in plaintext
        string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
        printf("ciphertext: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(plaintext); i++)
        {
            // Encrypt and preserve lower case characters
            if islower(plaintext[i])
            {
                // Position of the character in the alphabet
                int alphaPos = plaintext[i] + key - 97; 
                // Keep the number within the alphabet loop
                int wrappedChar = alphaPos % 26;
                printf("%c", wrappedChar + 97);
            }
            else if isupper(plaintext[i])
            {
                int alphaPos = plaintext[i] + key - 65;
                int wrappedChar = alphaPos % 26;
                printf("%c", wrappedChar + 65);
            }
            else 
            {
                printf("%c", plaintext[i]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   
    return 0;
}

int shift(char c)
{
    //TODO
    // If isUpper then minus 65
    if (isupper(c))
    {
        return c - 65;
    }

    // If isLower then minus 97
    else if (islower(c))
    {
        return c - 97;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you minimize your example even more? E.g. you're not using `shift` so you can leave that out. Also you can just set `key` to `1`(=`b`) to exclude the input as a source of errors.

Comment: I realised that, so I removed a big chunk of my code above to call my shift function I had below my code.

Answer (score 0):

This `int key = atoi(argv[1]);` is (probably) the root of the problem. It looks like it is left over from caesar exercise. `atoi` does not detect errors, so if you sent `b` as your argument, `key` would equal 0 because `b` cannot be converted to an int, and `hello` is `hello`.

Suggest you review the walkthrough again, especially Zamyla's panda example.

Comment: Thank you! I will and I kinda left some of my caesar code in my new one and wasn't calling my shift int. I'll check out Zamyla's panda example, cheers!